# How to pull specific data from different length string?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I got this type of sport activity data in excel:
[image: sports data]
I try to pull just a "calorie" value from column D to another cell.
Any suggestions how to pull this data?

Tried to do it by =MID function, but those strings are different length.
Any suggestions how to pull this data?

Comment: Which version of Excel do you have? Do  you have the TEXTSPLIT function?

Answer (score 1):

You could try a formula like as below,

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `E1`

```
=TEXTAFTER(TEXTBEFORE(D1,",""count"),"calorie"":")+0
```

---

Alternative approach, If you are not using **MS365**, then use the formula as shown below

[image]

• Formula used in cell `F1`

```
=REPLACE(LEFT(D1,FIND("""count",D1)-2),1,FIND("calorie",D1)+8,"")+0
```

---

Or, In **MS365** using `CHOOSECOLS()` & `TEXTSPLIT()`

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `G1`

```
=CHOOSECOLS(TEXTSPLIT(D1,{":",","},,1),8)/1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
=TEXTBEFORE(TEXTAFTER(A1,"""calorie"":"),",")
```

Answer (score 0):

Using VBA, you can use the `Split` method, since the pattern is the same:

```
Sub ExtractCalorie()
  Dim cel As String: cel = ActiveCell.Value
  'in the active cell is the string: {"duration":67,"altitude":0.0,"distance":21499,"calorie":89000,"count":0,"floor":0,"steps":0}
  Debug.Print Split(cel, ",")(3) 'it returns "calorie":89000
  'If only the value needed:
  Debug.Print Split(Split(cel, ",")(3), ":")(1) 'it returns 89000
End Sub
```

It can be easily transformed in a function, which works also as UDF, to be called from a formula in cell...